# alternative for Jquery scrollto

Tags: jquery

I'm searching a way to have a horizontal scroller on hyperlinks and I have been taking a look on the scrollto plugin but as it seems is really outdated. Is it possible to achive the same results just with simple jquery?

Comment: Please be more descriptive and show some code.  What is _"horizontal scroller on hyperlinks"_ supposed to do exactly?  Click a link and scroll the page sideways?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('#divToScroll').animate({'scrollTop': '20'}); // scroll to 20px
```

Or if you want relative scrolling:

```
$('#divToScroll').animate({'scrollTop': '+=20'}); // scroll to 20px below current position
```

Example fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/zq4a8/

Example fiddle for horizontal scroller:
http://jsfiddle.net/rGcWm/4/

```
$('#scroller').click(function() { $('#outer').animate({'scrollLeft': '+=20'}); });
$('#scroller_to').click(function() { $('#outer').animate({'scrollLeft': '20'}); });​
```

Comment: show me your markup and I'll lead you on

Comment: @lgt http://jsfiddle.net/zq4a8/

Comment: `scrollTop` is vertical scrolling (up/down) the page.  The OP said he wants _"horizontal scroller"_ (left/right, I assume).

Comment: @Sparky672 yeah just realised :s http://jsfiddle.net/rGcWm/4/

Comment: Right. And I'm checking now if animate can handle something like scrollLeft and scrollRight